# remove the use of shouldStop variable in python producer thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I have written a producer thread in python and I want to stop its execution whenever a certain event is set. I didnt know how to use `threading.Event` for this puspose. So, I wrote some code myself:-

I have used a `self.shouldStop` variable which is set to False by default. Whenever I wish to stop the execution of the producer thread, I set `p.shouldStop` to True

```
import Queue
import threading
import time

class ProducerThread( threading.Thread ):
    def __init__( self, q ):
        super( ProducerThread, self ).__init__()

        self._q = q
        self.shouldStop = False
    def run( self ):
        for i in range( 5 ):
            if self.shouldStop is True:
                return
            self._q.put( i )

class ConsumerThread( threading.Thread ):
    def __init__( self, q ):
        super( ConsumerThread, self ).__init__()
        self._q = q

    def run( self ):
        while True:
            data = self._q.get()
            if data == 'Stop':
                print 'returning from the thread as I got %s message' % data
                return
            print "%s got %s. Sleeping for %s seconds. %s" % ( self.getName(), data, data, time.time() )
            time.sleep( data )
            print "%s woke up from sleep after %s seconds %s" % ( self.getName(), data, time.time() )
    def stop( self ):
        self._q.put( "Stop" )
if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue.Queue( 1 )
    p = ProducerThread( q )
    t = ConsumerThread( q )
    p.start()
    t.start()
    p.shouldStop = True
    p.join()
    t.stop()
    t.join()
```

My question is:

Is there any better way of achieving this by removing the use of `shouldStop` and using `threading.Event`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to share the same event object among all threads (as you already did with the queue).

Then use [`is_set()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Event.is_set) to check wether the event was set or not.
You can also use [`wait()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Event.wait) (with a timeout) and catch the timeout error to find out wether the event was set or not.
I find the solution with `is_set()` easier to read, so that's what is posted below:

```
import Queue
import threading
import time

class ProducerThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, work_queue, shutdown_event):
        super(ProducerThread, self).__init__()

        self._work_queue     = work_queue
        self._shutdown_event = shutdown_event

    def run(self):
        for i in range(5):
            if self._shutdown_event.is_set():
                return
            else:
                self._work_queue.put(i)

class ConsumerThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, work_queue, shutdown_event):
        super(ConsumerThread, self).__init__()
        self._work_queue     = work_queue
        self._shutdown_event = shutdown_event

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                data = self._work_queue.get(timeout=1)
            except Queue.Empty:
                if self._shutdown_event.is_set():
                    print 'returning from thread; queue is empty and ' \
                          'shutdown_event.is_set() is True'
                    return
                else:
                    continue
            if self._shutdown_event.is_set():
                print 'returning from thread; shutdown_event.is_set() is True'
                return
            else:
                print "%s got %s. Sleeping for %s seconds. %s" % (
                    self.getName(), data, data, time.time())
                time.sleep(1.0+data/10)
                print "%s woke up from sleep after %s seconds %s" % (
                    self.getName(), str(1.0+data/10), time.time())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    work_queue = Queue.Queue(maxsize = 1)
    shutdown_event = threading.Event()
    producer = ProducerThread(work_queue, shutdown_event)
    consumer = ConsumerThread(work_queue, shutdown_event)
    producer.start()
    consumer.start()
    p
    time.sleep(10)
    print 'MainThread: calling shutdown_event.set()'
    shutdown_event.set()
    producer.join()
    consumer.join()
```

Comment: In the consumer thread, Shoudnt the `get` happen in the `else` part. This is because if `put` from Producer finishes first but `get` in the Consumer is still waiting for some data in the queue. In this case, the event will never reach the Consumer. Am I correct?

Comment: That's correct, but moving the `get` to the `else` will not fix the problem. Let's say you move the `get` to the `else`: now the `producer` has finished, but `shutdown_event` not yet set: the consumer's `if self._shutdown_event.is_set()` would evaluate to `False`, the `else` would be executed and the consumer thread would block on the call to `_work_queue.get()`.

Comment: The proper fix is to call `get`with a timeout and check the event state in case of timeout error too.